# Can't change in momentum be negative?

Tags: ideal-gas

I was going through a derivation, of Ideal gas equation, PV=1/3 mnc2 and the book showed the following...[image: Figure]

But I know that change in momentum should be final momentum-initial momentum. But if it is so PV = -1/3mnc2 ?!

For the full derivation http://www.antonine-education.co.uk/Pages/Physics_5/Thermal_Physics/THE_03/thermal_page_3.htm

Comment: You want the force on the _wall_, not on the object, so there's an extra minus sign.

Comment: Note that in this derivation, it's really only the *magnitude* of the momentum change that matters anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, momentum is a vector quantity and changes in momentum therefore have a directionality; in fact a change in a particle's momentum is an impulse $\vec I \approx \vec F ~\delta t,$ it has the same directionality as the average force which acted on the particle. In this case that is indeed negative as the wall "pushes the particle back in."

Probably the author just wanted to be lazy with their minus signs, as the pressure on the wall requires an application of Newton's Third Law: once we know the force of the wall on the particle, the force of the particle on the wall is just the negative of that, which is in the positive direction.

Comment: Please elaborate what have you meant by 'pushes the force in'.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Sorry, I misspoke. I have corrected it now.

Comment: (Asking in context of your entire answer) Doesn't the impulse per unit time here give the force acting on the wall?

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Not directly, only after using Newton's third law. The negative impulse that you're talking about is an impulse on the particle, not on the wall. However because the force is provided by the wall, Newton's third law then tells you the force of the particle on the wall as the negative of the force of the wall on the particle.